# Best way to disable cobertura test for all the child modules from the parent pom

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, cobertura, parent-pom

I am trying to do a maven clean install on my parent pom.xml file by using the below command-

```
mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true -Dmaven.it.skip=true -DcoberturaHaltOnError=false
```

But somehow everytime, I am always getting the below error-

```
[INFO] --- cobertura-maven-plugin:2.5.2:check (default) @ tac-core ---
[INFO] Cobertura 1.9.4.1 - GNU GPL License (NO WARRANTY) - See COPYRIGHT file
Cobertura: Loaded information on 237 classes.

[ERROR] com.somehost.core.exception.LockedException failed check. Line coverage rate of 0.0% is below 80.0%
com.somehost.core.dao.impl.DAOReadOnlyImpl failed check. Branch coverage rate of 0.0% is below 90.0%
com.somehost.core.dao.impl.DAOReadOnlyImpl failed check. Line coverage rate of 0.0% is below 80.0%
com.somehost.core.service.Service failed check. Branch coverage rate of 0.0% is below 90.0%
com.somehost.core.service.Service failed check. Line coverage rate of 0.0% is below 80.0%
com.somehost.core.msg.client.StoreResponse failed check. Branch coverage rate of 0.0% is below 90.0%

// followed by other errors
```

I am not sure how to skip this cobertura test in my parent pom.xml file in such a way such that child modules doesn't get failed. From the above error it looks like my core module is getting failed (see my parent pom.xml file below)

Below is my parent pom.xml file-

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>com.somehost</groupId>
   <artifactId>tac-parent</artifactId>
   <version>MAIN</version>
   <packaging>pom</packaging>
   <name>Host-TAC</name>

   <properties>
      <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
      <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
      <release.version>MAIN</release.version>
      <cobertura.version>1.9.4</cobertura.version>
      <maven.test.skip>false</maven.test.skip>
      <maven.it.skip>false</maven.it.skip>
      <coberturaHaltOnError>true</coberturaHaltOnError>
   </properties>

   <modules>
      <module>core</module>
      <module>webapp</module>
      <module>client</module>
      <module>panner</module>
   </modules>

   <pluginRepositories>
      <pluginRepository>
         <id>caucho</id>
         <name>Caucho</name>
         <url>http://caucho.com/m2-snapshot</url>
      </pluginRepository>
   </pluginRepositories>

   <repositories>
      <repository>
         <id>caucho.maven-repo</id>
         <name>Caucho Repository</name>
         <url>http://caucho.com/m2-snapshot</url>
      </repository>
      <repository>
         <id>java.net-Public</id>
         <name>Maven Java Net Snapshots and Releases</name>
         <url>https://maven.java.net/content/groups/public/</url>
      </repository>
   </repositories>

   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.caucho</groupId>
         <artifactId>resin</artifactId>
         <version>4.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
         <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.caucho</groupId>
         <artifactId>resin-javaee</artifactId>
         <version>4.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
         <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
         <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
         <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
         <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
         <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
         <version>2.2.4</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
         <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
         <version>2.2.4-1</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.host</groupId>
         <artifactId>trustedsource</artifactId>
         <version>2.2.0.2</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
         <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
         <version>12.0</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
         <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
         <version>1.6.4</version>
      </dependency>
      <!--
             <dependency>
               <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
               <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
               <version>1.6.4</version>
            </dependency>
      -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
         <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
         <version>1.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
         <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
         <version>1.6.4</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
         <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
         <version>6.3</version>
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
         <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
         <version>1.6.4</version>
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>

   </dependencies>

   <dependencyManagement>
      <dependencies>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.somehost</groupId>
            <artifactId>tac-core</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
         </dependency>

         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.somehost</groupId>
            <artifactId>tac-client</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
         </dependency>

         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.somehost</groupId>
            <artifactId>tac-scanner</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
         </dependency>

         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.somehost</groupId>
            <artifactId>tac-webapp</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
         </dependency>
      </dependencies>
   </dependencyManagement>


 <profiles>
      <profile>
         <id>cobertura-instrument</id>
         <activation>
            <property>
               <name>cobertura-build</name>
            </property>
         </activation>
         <modules>
            <module>tac-cobertura</module>
         </modules>
         <build>
            <plugins>
               <plugin>
                  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                  <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>2.5.2</version>
                   <configuration>
                           <check>
                             <haltOnFailure>${coberturaHaltOnerror}</haltOnFailure>
                             <totalLineRate>90</totalLineRate>
                             <totalBranchRate>90</totalBranchRate>
                           </check>
                           <formats>
                             <format>html</format>
                           </formats>
                   </configuration>
                  <executions>
                     <execution>
                        <id>instrument-code</id>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                           <goal>instrument</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                           <attach>true</attach>
                        </configuration>
                     </execution>
                  </executions>
               </plugin>
               <plugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>2.2.1</version>
                  <executions>
                     <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                           <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                     </execution>
                  </executions>
                  <inherited>true</inherited>
               </plugin>
            </plugins>
         </build>
         <dependencies>
            <dependency>
               <groupId>net.sourceforge.cobertura</groupId>
             <artifactId>cobertura-runtime</artifactId>
               <version>${cobertura.version}</version>
               <scope>provided</scope>
               <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
         </dependencies>
      </profile>
   </profiles>


   <build>
      <finalName>tac-${project.version}-r${buildNumber}</finalName>
      <pluginManagement>
         <plugins>
            <plugin>
               <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
               <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>1.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
               <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
               <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>2.5.2</version>
            </plugin>
         </plugins>
      </pluginManagement>

      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                  <phase>validate</phase>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>create</goal>
                  </goals>
               </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
               <useLastCommittedRevision>true</useLastCommittedRevision>
               <scmDirectory>${project.parent.basedir}</scmDirectory>
               <doCheck>false</doCheck>
               <doUpdate>false</doUpdate>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.6</version>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                  <id>bundle-manifest</id>
                  <phase>process-resources</phase>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>manifest</goal>
                  </goals>
               </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
               <supportedProjectTypes>
                  <supportedProjectType>jar</supportedProjectType>
                  <supportedProjectType>bundle</supportedProjectType>
                  <supportedProjectType>war</supportedProjectType>
               </supportedProjectTypes>
               <instructions>
                  <Build-version>${buildNumber}</Build-version>
               </instructions>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
            <configuration>
               <instrumentation>
                  <includes>
                     <include>com/somehost/**/*.class</include>
                  </includes>
                  <!--
                  <ignores>
                     <ignore>com.example.boringcode.*</ignore>
                  </ignores>
                  -->
                  <!--
                  <excludes>
                     <exclude>com/example/dullcode/**/*.class</exclude>
                     <exclude>com/example/**/*Test.class</exclude>
                  </excludes>
                  -->
               </instrumentation>
               <check>
                  <branchRate>85</branchRate>
                  <lineRate>85</lineRate>
                  <haltOnFailure>true</haltOnFailure>
                  <totalBranchRate>85</totalBranchRate>
                  <totalLineRate>85</totalLineRate>
                  <packageLineRate>85</packageLineRate>
                  <packageBranchRate>85</packageBranchRate>
                  <regexes>
                     <regex>
                        <pattern>com.somehost.*</pattern>
                        <branchRate>90</branchRate>
                        <lineRate>80</lineRate>
                     </regex>
                  </regexes>
               </check>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>clean</goal>
                     <goal>check</goal>
                  </goals>
               </execution>
            </executions>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>

   <reporting>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehause.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
            <configuration>
               <formats>
                  <format>html</format>
                  <format>xml</format>
               </formats>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </reporting>
</project>
```

**Updated Code:-**

Below is my updated parent pom.xml file but still I am getting the same error-

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>com.somehost</groupId>
   <artifactId>tac-parent</artifactId>
   <version>MAIN</version>
   <packaging>pom</packaging>
   <name>Host-TAC</name>

   <properties>
      <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
      <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
      <release.version>MAIN</release.version>
      <cobertura.version>1.9.4</cobertura.version>
      <maven.test.skip>false</maven.test.skip>
      <maven.it.skip>false</maven.it.skip>
      <coberturaHaltOnError>true</coberturaHaltOnError>
   </properties>

   <modules>
      <module>core</module>
      <module>webapp</module>
      <module>client</module>
      <module>panner</module>
   </modules>

   <pluginRepositories>
      <pluginRepository>
         <id>caucho</id>
         <name>Caucho</name>
         <url>http://caucho.com/m2-snapshot</url>
      </pluginRepository>
   </pluginRepositories>

   <repositories>
      <repository>
         <id>caucho.maven-repo</id>
         <name>Caucho Repository</name>
         <url>http://caucho.com/m2-snapshot</url>
      </repository>
      <repository>
         <id>java.net-Public</id>
         <name>Maven Java Net Snapshots and Releases</name>
         <url>https://maven.java.net/content/groups/public/</url>
      </repository>
   </repositories>

   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.caucho</groupId>
         <artifactId>resin</artifactId>
         <version>4.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
         <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.caucho</groupId>
         <artifactId>resin-javaee</artifactId>
         <version>4.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
         <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
         <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
         <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
         <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
         <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
         <version>2.2.4</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
         <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
         <version>2.2.4-1</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.host</groupId>
         <artifactId>trustedsource</artifactId>
         <version>2.2.0.2</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
         <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
         <version>12.0</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
         <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
         <version>1.6.4</version>
      </dependency>
      <!--
             <dependency>
               <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
               <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
               <version>1.6.4</version>
            </dependency>
      -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
         <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
         <version>1.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
         <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
         <version>1.6.4</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
         <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
         <version>6.3</version>
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
         <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
         <version>1.6.4</version>
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>

   </dependencies>

   <dependencyManagement>
      <dependencies>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.somehost</groupId>
            <artifactId>tac-core</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
         </dependency>

         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.somehost</groupId>
            <artifactId>tac-client</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
         </dependency>

         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.somehost</groupId>
            <artifactId>tac-scanner</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
         </dependency>

         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.somehost</groupId>
            <artifactId>tac-webapp</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
         </dependency>
      </dependencies>
   </dependencyManagement>


 <profiles>
      <profile>
         <id>cobertura-instrument</id>
         <activation>
            <property>
               <name>cobertura-build</name>
            </property>
         </activation>
         <modules>
            <module>tac-cobertura</module>
         </modules>
         <build>
            <plugins>
               <plugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>2.2.1</version>
                  <executions>
                     <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                           <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                     </execution>
                  </executions>
                  <inherited>true</inherited>
               </plugin>
            </plugins>
         </build>
         <dependencies>
            <dependency>
               <groupId>net.sourceforge.cobertura</groupId>
             <artifactId>cobertura-runtime</artifactId>
               <version>${cobertura.version}</version>
               <scope>provided</scope>
               <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
         </dependencies>
      </profile>
   </profiles>


<build>
      <finalName>mac-${project.version}-r${buildNumber}</finalName>
      <pluginManagement>
         <plugins>
            <plugin>
               <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
               <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>1.0</version>
            </plugin>
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.2</version>
                 <inherited>false</inherited>
                 <configuration>
                     <skip>true</skip>
                         <check>
                           <haltOnFailure>${coberturaHaltOnerror}</haltOnFailure>
                           <totalLineRate>90</totalLineRate>
                           <totalBranchRate>90</totalBranchRate>
                         </check>
                         <formats>
                           <format>html</format>
                         </formats>
                 </configuration>
                <executions>
                   <execution>
                      <id>instrument-code</id>
                      <phase>process-classes</phase>
                      <goals>
                         <goal>instrument</goal>
                      </goals>
                      <configuration>
                         <attach>true</attach>
                      </configuration>
                   </execution>
                </executions>
             </plugin>
         </plugins>
      </pluginManagement>

      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                  <phase>validate</phase>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>create</goal>
                  </goals>
               </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
               <useLastCommittedRevision>true</useLastCommittedRevision>
               <scmDirectory>${project.parent.basedir}</scmDirectory>
               <doCheck>false</doCheck>
               <doUpdate>false</doUpdate>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.6</version>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                  <id>bundle-manifest</id>
                  <phase>process-resources</phase>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>manifest</goal>
                  </goals>
               </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
               <supportedProjectTypes>
                  <supportedProjectType>jar</supportedProjectType>
                  <supportedProjectType>bundle</supportedProjectType>
                  <supportedProjectType>war</supportedProjectType>
               </supportedProjectTypes>
               <instructions>
                  <Build-version>${buildNumber}</Build-version>
               </instructions>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
            <configuration>
               <instrumentation>
                  <includes>
                     <include>com/somehost/**/*.class</include>
                  </includes>
                  <!--
                  <ignores>
                     <ignore>com.example.boringcode.*</ignore>
                  </ignores>
                  -->
                  <!--
                  <excludes>
                     <exclude>com/example/dullcode/**/*.class</exclude>
                     <exclude>com/example/**/*Test.class</exclude>
                  </excludes>
                  -->
               </instrumentation>
               <check>
                  <branchRate>85</branchRate>
                  <lineRate>85</lineRate>
                  <haltOnFailure>true</haltOnFailure>
                  <totalBranchRate>85</totalBranchRate>
                  <totalLineRate>85</totalLineRate>
                  <packageLineRate>85</packageLineRate>
                  <packageBranchRate>85</packageBranchRate>
                  <regexes>
                     <regex>
                        <pattern>com.somehost.*</pattern>
                        <branchRate>90</branchRate>
                        <lineRate>80</lineRate>
                     </regex>
                  </regexes>
               </check>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>clean</goal>
                     <goal>check</goal>
                  </goals>
               </execution>
            </executions>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>

   <reporting>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehause.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
            <configuration>
               <formats>
                  <format>html</format>
                  <format>xml</format>
               </formats>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </reporting>
</project>
```

And after this change, I am running it like this-

```
mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true -Dmaven.it.skip=true -DcoberturaHaltOnError=false
```

And still, I am getting the same error-

```
[INFO] --- cobertura-maven-plugin:2.5.2:check (default) @ tac-core ---
[INFO] Cobertura 1.9.4.1 - GNU GPL License (NO WARRANTY) - See COPYRIGHT file
Cobertura: Loaded information on 237 classes.

[ERROR] com.somehost.core.exception.LockedException failed check. Line coverage rate of 0.0% is below 80.0%
com.somehost.core.dao.impl.DAOReadOnlyImpl failed check. Branch coverage rate of 0.0% is below 90.0%
com.somehost.core.dao.impl.DAOReadOnlyImpl failed check. Line coverage rate of 0.0% is below 80.0%
com.somehost.core.service.Service failed check. Branch coverage rate of 0.0% is below 90.0%
com.somehost.core.service.Service failed check. Line coverage rate of 0.0% is below 80.0%
com.somehost.core.msg.client.StoreResponse failed check. Branch coverage rate of 0.0% is below 90.0%

// followed by other errors
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the plugin with the configuration for its modules to pluginManagement and add the following

```
<project>
...
 <build>
  <pluginManagement>
   <plugins>
    <!-- put here your original plugin configuration for the children -->
    <plugin>
     <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
     <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>
   </plugins>   
  </pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.2</version>
    <inherited>false</inherited>
    <configuration>
     <skip>true</skip>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

the `inherited=false` makes it possible to set the configuration only for this project, not those which use it as a parent.

Comment: I was not able to understand your first line `Move the plugin with the configuration for its modules to pluginManagement`, what I am supposed to do? If possible, can you provide the full pom.xml file with the necessary changes by which I will be able to understand much better.. Thanks..

Comment: Move your current cobertura-maven-plugin to <project><build><pluginManangement><plugins>

Comment: I just updated the question with the suggestion you just gave but still I am getting the same exception... I am not sure what wrong I did this time..

Comment: Please read everything carefully. http://pastebin.com/4kAiL4FH shows the required cobertura-maven-plugin configuration.

Answer (score 3):

To make it much more simpler

mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip -Dcobertura.skip=true

This will skip test as well as cobertura low coverage build won't fail.By executing this from parent project will help. It's important to skip both together otherwise It will fail the build either due to test or due to cobertura.

So far without changing anything this is the most easiest way and It worked.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question.

Comment: It disables cobertura test for all child modules...I believe that's what this question about.

Comment: I understand that this question is already answered however It didn't help when applied and I found alternative solution which may help to someone. Hence it's always good to share alternate way of solving problem.

Comment: I'm using the command "mvn install -Dmaven.test.skip=true -Dcobertura.skip=true" to skip Test and Cobertura, but it's still running cobertura. Any help on this ? Maven version : v3.6.3 cobertura-maven-plugin : v2.7

Comment: Krupa, first of all it's not -Dmaven.test.skip=true                          it's just - Dmaven.test.skip and then -Dcobertura.skip=true hence if you copy and paste exactly what it's return then it must work.